# Lang libs for words proccessing to required grammatical cases?

Tags: java, lucene, languagetool

Is there any libs that can transform input words to needed grammatical case (genitive, nominative etc.) and plural/singular forms ?

Basically I'm interested in english, german, russian languages.

I know there are libs like `apache lucene` and `language-tool`, but seems like they can do stemming and lemmatization and can be used for search and spell-checking, but not for text transformations.

Comment: Transforming text is a particularly hard problem for machines because they need to understand those sentences in some way and not just check a few rules like spell checkers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org): it contains a lemmatizer and also the opposite, which we call a synthesizer: you can get from e.g. "walks" to its base form "walk" and then to all its form, e.g. the gerund "walking". Which form is needed is up to you to find out, though. The relevant code for English is at https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-language-modules/en/src/main/java/org/languagetool/synthesis/en/EnglishSynthesizer.java, Russian and German are supported, too.